# Is it possible to get an Int-Array-Pointer on a Char-Array (or sth similar)?

Tags: c, pointers, networking, casting

I want to write five integers (as 32-bit-integers) into a char-array. Currently i make 5 individual int-pointers to specific places in the char-array, but instead i want just want one pointer. The code below works, but i want a less clumsy solution.

```
int uSensorID = 7;
int uSensorTypeEnum = 5;
int currentSensorValue = 15;
static const int messageSize = 20;               
static char dataToSendBuffer[messageSize + 1];    

static int* PointerSensorIDInSendBufferCharArray = (int*)(&dataToSendBuffer[0]);
static int* PointerFirstSeparatorInSendBufferCharArray = (int*)(&dataToSendBuffer[4]);
static int* PointerSensorTypeInSendBuffer = (int*)(&dataToSendBuffer[8]);
static int* PointerSecondSeparatorInSendBufferCharArray = (int*)(&dataToSendBuffer[12]);
static int* PointerCurrentSensorValueInSendBuffer = (int*)(&dataToSendBuffer[16]);

*PointerSensorIDInSendBufferCharArray = htonl(stoi(uSensorID);
*PointerFirstSeparatorInSendBufferCharArray = -1;                       
*PointerSensorTypeInSendBuffer = htonl(uSensorTypeEnum);
*PointerSecondSeparatorInSendBufferCharArray = -1;
*PointerCurrentSensorValueInSendBuffer = htonl(currentSensorValue);
```

Ideally i would want something like an Int-Array-Pointer that points to the memory-adress of the first element of the char-array, so the code should look something like this (but my code doesn't work, just to give an idea):

```
int uSensorID = 7;
int uSensorTypeEnum = 5;
int currentSensorValue = 15;
static const int messageSize = 20;                 
static char dataToSendBuffer[messageSize + 1];            

int* IntPointerToDataToSendBuffer[] = (int* [])(&dataToSendBuffer);
*IntPointerToDataToSendBuffer[0] = htonl(stoi(uSensorID);
*IntPointerToDataToSendBuffer[1] = -1;
*IntPointerToDataToSendBuffer[2] = htonl(uSensorTypeEnum);
*IntPointerToDataToSendBuffer[3] = -1;
*IntPointerToDataToSendBuffer[4] = htonl(currentSensorValue);
```

Is this possible (or something similar where one doesn't need 5 individual pointers)?
(I want to use ideally only use one array, so not just copy the array (multiple pointers is okay). The static is used as this will later be looped over endlessly.)

Regards and thanks for any help

Comment: please tag only the language you are using. C and C++ are two different languages

Comment: why not use an int array?

Comment: @stark
Later this will be used in an function that expects iirc char-array (or maybe char*), so the other way around (char-array-pointer or char-pointer on int-array) would also be ok, but not just int-array with int-pointer

Comment: you can always use an int array as a char array, but the reverse is not true. A char array may not be properly aligned to hold ints.

Comment: When using an int-array where some integers are 0 inbetween, would one get a problem using char* with it? As the pointer/programms thinks the array ends there or (because of the null)?

Comment: Mixing assignments with and without `htonl` might be wrong. It is not guaranteed that `htonl(-1) == -1` even if it is the case on commonly used platforms. I suggest to [edit] your question and add some background information what you want to achieve and how you want to use `dataToSendBuffer`. Show the function that expects this buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `union` as a wrapper then access the data either as bytes or 32 bit integers. This is well-defined and solves problems with alignment and pointer aliasing. It's a common technique for serialization/deserialization in C.

```
typedef union
{
  uint8_t  u8  [MESSAGE_SIZE];
  uint32_t u32 [MESSAGE_SIZE/4]
} data_buf_t;

static data_buf_t buf = { .u8 = { /* init this to something */ } };
buf.u32[0] = htonl(...);
```

What you *cannot* do is to take a raw character buffer and cast it to an `int*` and hack away from there - character buffers can have different alignment than `int` and to make things worse, C doesn't define what will happen, which could in turn lead to incorrect program behavior. It is fine to access any variable through a character type pointer in C - *but not the other way around*!

Also for the sake of readability, please avoid extremely long identifier names.

Answer (score -1):

Any pointer can be used like an array, there is no difference between a pointer pointing to a single value or to the first value of an array. Of course the behavior is undefined if you use the pointer to access invalid memory.

`*pointer` is equivalent to `pointer[0]`.

The following code snippet is only intended to show how to use a pointer as an array based on the original code from the question. It does not fix other problems in the original code.

```
int* IntPointerToDataToSendBuffer = (int*)(&dataToSendBuffer);
IntPointerToDataToSendBuffer[0] = htonl(stoi(uSensorID); /* unrelated syntax error here */
IntPointerToDataToSendBuffer[1] = -1;
```

etc.

**But: Casting a `char *` to an `int *` and dereferencing this pointer is wrong.**

This may seem to work on some platforms (as this is one possible variant of undefined behavior), and I have often seen it in real-world code.
Apart from the violation of formal rules you might get problems on some platforms. An `int*` may need stricter alignment than a `char *`. Depending on your platform this can result in compiler warnings, slower execution or program abort caused by an alignment trap if the `char` array does not happen to be aligned as required for an `int` array.
I've also seen these problems, and I would never do this way.

You should **do it the other way round**: Use an `int` array and cast it to a `char *` in order to use it as a byte array / buffer.

Comment: When using an int-array where some integers are 0 inbetween, would one get a problem using char* with it?
As the pointer/programms thinks the array terminates there or?

Comment: @someuser47 A `char` value 0 is only relevant if you use the `char` array as a C string, e.g. by using functions like `strcpy` or `printf`'s format `%s`. If you store binary data, the size of the data must be specified or must be implied by the function.

Comment: "Any pointer can be used like an array" No! `dataToSendBuffer` might indeed be misaligned but `IntPointerToDataToSendBuffer[0]` also invokes undefined behavior by strict aliasing violation. This answer is just misleading, don't write code like this.